# В чем заключается ошибка? Определение високосного года на C++

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку.
Напишите программу, которая определяет, является ли данный год високосным.
Високосными годами считаются те годы, порядковый номер которых либо кратен 4, но при этом не кратен 100, либо кратен 400 (например, 2000-й год являлся високосным, а 2100-й будет невисокосным годом).
Программа должна корректно работать на числах 1900≤n≤3000.
Выведите "Високосный" в случае, если считанный год является високосным и "Обычный" в обратном случае.
Ввод:
2100
Вывод:
Обычный
Ввод:
2000
Вывод:
Високосный.
Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x;
cin >> x;
if(x % 400 == 0);
cout<<"Високосный год\n";
if()
{
if(x % 4 == 0);
if(x % 100 != 0 );
cout << "Високосный год\n";

}
else cout "Обычный год\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if()` - ?? *(нужно ещё 4 символа...)*

Comment: `if(x % 4 == 0);` - это что делает?

Comment: Проверяет остаток от деления на 4,чтобы выяснить какой год Високосный или Обычный

Comment: нет, не проверяет остаток от деления на 4,чтобы выяснить какой год Високосный или Обычный

Comment: Почему не проверяет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О точке с запятой вам  Igor уже пояснил. А я просто добавлю: можно просто одной строкой:

```
cout << ((y%400==0)||((y%4==0)&&(y%100!=0)) ? "Високосный":"Обычный") << " год";
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему Вы поставили точки с запятыми после условных операторов? С ними они просто обрабатываются и идут дальше вне зависимости от результата